# AutoCompletion KMM

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-multiplatform

I have been working on a KMM project for 2 months, and I never had any problem.
This thursday morning, I see that my Android Studio doesn't detect the shared module of KMM anymore, but only in the IDE, because it always compiles correctly.
After having Clean, Rebuild, Invalid Caches/Restart, I can't find the autoCompletion.
I try a lot of change on Android Studio but nothing work.

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Is KMM IDE plugin enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is activated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've been having this a couple of times. Usually for multi module KMM projects.

In most cases updating either Android Studio, Kotlin version or Gradle/AGP versions, but also switching from Android Studio to IntellIJ in some cases solved the issue for me.

Could you make sure you are using latest versions?

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
Yes, I have updated my android studio preview, as well as the KMM plugin.
I use version 7.0.2 of gradle.
As for intellij, you have to use a particular version to have access to the KMM plugin?

Comment: I think the KMM plugin is Android Studio only, I had problems on AGP 7.0.2, a recent update to AGP 7.1.0 & Gradle 7.2 fixed it

Comment: I modified it, but I still have the same problem... Thanks anyway!